# Flip a coin whilst counting attempts until you get 5 tails in a row

Tags: vb.net

What I am trying to do:

I want to loop infinitely until I get 5 tails in a row. I also want to show the number of attempts it took to be able to achieve 5 tails in a row

Here is what I have:

```
Dim number = rand.Next(1, 3)

If number = 1 Then
    RichTextBox1.Text += "Tails" & vbNewLine
ElseIf number = 2 Then
    RichTextBox1.Text += "Heads" & vbNewLine
End If

number = rand.Next(1, 3)
```

I haven't been able to figure it out. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Here we go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezk76t25.aspx

Comment: Take a piece of paper, a pen and a coin. Imagine you wouldn´t have no computer to solve this issue, but only your brain. How would you write a set of simple constructions so your little brother could execute them to achieve the required result? Start with your first step, e.g. "I need a variable to count my tries". 2nd: "I do the following steps until the condition x is fullfilled", ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a counter variable that stores how often you already had tails. `While tailCount < 5` will break this loop if you have found 5. Another counter will count the total attempts:

```
Dim rand As New Random()
Dim maxTailCount = 5
Dim attempts = 0
Dim tailCount = 0

While tailCount < maxTailCount
    attempts += 1
    Dim number = rand.Next(1, 3)
    If number = 1 Then
        tailCount += 1
    Else
        tailCount = 0 ' because they must be "in a row"
    End If
End While
Console.WriteLine("Found {0} tails, total attempts: {1}", maxTailCount, attempts)
```